# Angularjs not working in docker file npm install Write after End erro

Tags: angularjs, docker, npm, npm-install

Update: so i found a "solution" I can't name the container client. I must have a hidden container somewhere i cant delete

So I'm trying to setup a docker file environment for a mean stack, was having trouble getting angular to restart on change. I had tried a few things and was testing to make sure it was Docker composeb but now when i try to run the docker file it gets npm install and then has npm err

I have got to point where i completely uninstalled both angular nodejs npm and docker and still problems

```
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3d1dc570d73c
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6ee5da6bd050
Step 4/8 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2b7d8e3010d5
Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 90163baffdb6
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END
npm ERR! write after end
npm ERR! code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END
npm ERR! write after end
npm ERR! code ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END
npm ERR! write after end

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-02T20_12_17_764Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

err log

```
15037 silly pacote data for sha1-4PyVEztu8nbNyIh82vJKpvFW+Po= not present. Using manifest.
15038 verbose stack Error: write after end
15038 verbose stack     at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12)
15038 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
15038 verbose stack     at PassThrough.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:553:10)
15038 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.entry.on (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/extract-stream.js:19:41)
15038 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
15038 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (events.js:211:7)
15038 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.emit (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:287:25)
15038 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.[maybeEmitEnd] (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:240:12)
15038 verbose stack     at ReadEntry.end (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:153:27)
15038 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeBody] (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:210:13)
15038 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeChunkSub] (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:391:40)
15038 verbose stack     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:362:30)
15038 verbose stack     at Unzip.(anonymous function).on.chunk (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/parse.js:291:59)
15038 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
15038 verbose stack     at Unzip.emit (events.js:211:7)
15038 verbose stack     at Unzip.emit (/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js:287:25)
15039 verbose cwd /
15040 verbose Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
15041 verbose argv "/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/node" "/home/jacob/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
15042 verbose node v8.9.4
15043 verbose npm  v5.7.1
15044 error write after end
15045 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: looks like an NPM install error only, doesn't seem to have anything to do with Docker

Comment: looks like the NPM package pacote is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, solution was to add package-lock.json to docker container too and make sure you don't added built angular app to container.

Comment: i fixed it eventually but i forget now how i did it

Answer (score 0):

It's an [issue](https://github.com/zkat/pacote/issues/142) in [pacote](https://github.com/zkat/pacote) package npm 5.7.1 depends on. [npm issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19989) to follow.

Just downgrade npm to 5.6.0 version:

```
npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```